# Why is Get-ChildItem inside a Function Access denied after correct New-PSDrive? (It works outside of the function scope.)

Tags: powershell, credentials, get-childitem, new-psdrive

This doesnt work

```
function ImportProcess{
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$XMLPath
    )

  
    $sourcePath = $XMLPath
    $DestPath = split-path "$sourcePath" -Parent #this gives format without slash at and and makes powerShell *very happy*
    write-host "connecting to Dir"
    New-PSDrive -Name "Drive" -PSProvider FileSystem -Credential $global:cred -Root "$DestPath" | Out-Null
    write-host "done"

    write-host "getting all xml files"
    $temp1 = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath
}
```

I want to put this inside a function and access the files in the path and this below works. I got this methode from [using credentials to get-childitem on other server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566026/using-credentials-to-get-childitem-on-other-server/22614523#22614523?newreg=679213e666364b399d2d2ffc84f313a4)

```
$sourcePath = "path"
$DestPath = split-path "$sourcePath" -Parent #this gives format without slash at and and makes powerShell *very happy*
write-host "connecting to Dir"
New-PSDrive -Name "Drive" -PSProvider FileSystem -Credential $global:cred -Root "$DestPath" | Out-Null
write-host "done"

write-host "getting all xml files"
$temp1 = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath
```

I tried different scopes in New-PSDrive and set-location before get-childitem, aswell as setting the Path to the Drive name + needed subdir

i removed the part where i get the credentials, because all works but as soon as i put the process in a function i get "Get-ChildItem : Access is denied"

Comment: Show us how you invoke/call the `ImportProcess` function.

Comment: ImportProcess -XMLPath "path" @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: That would explain your problem. The parameter name is `XMLPath`, so you need to call `ImportProcess -XMLPath "<path goes here>"`

Comment: I use the correct parameter name. I just checked. (The var names are bit different in my script so i have to change them here.)  when i debug i get the correct path as output inside the function.
Thanks for your help! @MathiasR.Jessen